# how to use ajax with jquery in order to get a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json file that I want to add to the code using ajax. But, I cannot make it work. I do not know much about ajax and JQuery.

The json file has an array that I want to use in different parts of the js code. Also, I created a variable to allocate and use the json file from ajax, but i don't know how to use it in the rest of the code in order to get the data inside.

Below is the ajax that I'm having issues with.

This is the JavaScript

```
function Guardar() {
    datosJSON.nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    datosJSON.edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
    datosJSON.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    datosJSON.telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
    localStorage.setItem('datosSolictante', JSON.stringify(datosJSON));
} // Cierre funcion guardar


function checkData() {
    console.log(todaInfo);
    console.log(((nombre.value) && (edad.value) && (email.value) && (telefono.value)));
    if ((nombre.value) && (edad.value) && (email.value) && (telefono.value)) {
    console.log(todaInfo);
    todaInfo.innerHTML = ` ${nombre.value} ${edad.value} ${email.value} ${telefono.value}  `;
}} // Cierre funcion checkData


window.onload = function() {
    let todaInfo = document.getElementById('todaInfo');
    let info = document.getElementById('info');
    console.log(todaInfo);
    console.log(info);
    todaInfo.innerHTML = '';
    var guardado = document.getElementById('guardado');
    guardado.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (checkData) {
        guardado.innerHTML = "Guardado";
    }
});
};

guardado.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if ((nombre.value.length > 0) && (edad.value.length > 0) && (email.value.length > 0) && (telefono.value.length > 0)) {
        info.innerHTML += "<th>Informacion del cliente</th><tr><td>Nombre: " + nombre.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Edad: " + edad.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Email: " + email.value + "</tr></td><tr><td>Telefono: " + telefono.value + "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    nombre.value = "";
    edad.value = "";
    email.value = "";
    telefono.value = "";
});



var archivoAjax = $.ajax();
  
$.ajax({
      url: 'autos.JSON',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);        
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
          console.log(jqXHR),
          console.log(`Error -> Status: ${status} - Error: ${error}`);
        }  
    });


// Constructor
class Seguro {
    constructor(marca, modelo, year, tipo, precio) {
      this.marca = marca;
      this.modelo = modelo;
      this.year = year;
      this.tipo = tipo;
      this.precio = precio;
    }
  
    // Realiza la cotización con los datos
    cotizarSeguro() {
      const base = 1000;
      let poliza = ((this.precio * 0.05) / 12);
  
      if (poliza < 1000) {
        poliza += base;
      }
      // Leer el año
      const diferencia = new Date().getFullYear() - this.year;
  
      // Cada año que la diferencia es mayor, el costo va a reducirse un 3%
      poliza -= ((diferencia * 3) * poliza) / 100;
  
      //Si el seguro es completo se multiplica por un 30% más
      if (this.tipo === 'terceros-ampliada') {
        poliza *= 1.30;
      } else if (this.tipo === 'todo-riesgo') {
        poliza *= 1.45;
      }
  
      return poliza;
    }
  }
  
  window.onload = () => {
    //Selecciono los select de Marca y Modelo
    const selectMarca = document.querySelector('#marca');
    const selectModel = document.querySelector('#modelo');
  
    //Selecciono el formulario
    const formulario = document.querySelector('#cotizar-seguro');
  
    //Manejador de evento "submit" del formulario
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', cotizarSeguro);
  
    //Llamo función lista select para armar un arreglo con las distintas marcas
    const marcas = listaSelect(archivoAjax, "marca");
  
    //Cargo las marcas en el Select
    cargarContenido(marcas, selectMarca);
  
    //Cargar fechas
    llenarFecha();
  
    //Manejador de evento "change" del select de marca (Cuando el usuario selecciona una marca)
    selectMarca.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      //Borro el contenido del select de Modelo
      selectModel.innerHTML = '<option value=""> Seleccionar </option>';
  
      //Filtro el arreglo de autos y me quedo con los que tienen la marca seleccionada
      const modelos = archivoAjax.filter(elem => elem.marca.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-') == e.target.value);
  
      //Llamo función lista select para armar un arreglo con los distintos modelos
      const listaModelos = listaSelect(modelos, "modelo");
  
      //Cargo los modelos en el select de modelos
      cargarContenido(listaModelos, selectModel);
    });
  } // Cierre de windows.onload
  
  //Función para generar y cargar en el select de Año los distintos años
  function llenarFecha() {
    const max = new Date().getFullYear(),
      min = max - 70;
  
    const selectYear = document.querySelector('#year');
  
    for (let i = max; i > min; i--) {
      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = i;
      option.textContent = i;
      selectYear.appendChild(option);
    }
  } // Cierre funcion llenarFecha
  
  // Cargo contenido en los Select
  function cargarContenido(array, select) {
    array.forEach(element => {
      let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = element.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
      option.textContent = element;
      select.appendChild(option);
    })
  } // Cierre funcion cargarContenido
  
  
  // Genero listado (arreglo) para los select
  function listaSelect(array, key) {
    const listado = [];
  
    array.forEach(elem => {
      if (!listado.includes(elem[key])) {
        listado.push(elem[key]);
      }
    })
    return listado.sort();
  } // Cierre funcion listaSelect
  
  //Función manejadora para el evento "submit" del formulario
  function cotizarSeguro(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    // Leer la marca seleccionada
    const marca = document.querySelector('#marca').value;
  
    // Leer la marca seleccionada
    const modelo = document.querySelector('#modelo').value;
  
    // Leer el año seleccionado
    const year = document.querySelector('#year').value;
  
    // Leer el tipo de cobertura
    const tipo = document.querySelector('input[name="tipo"]:checked').value;
  
    //Verifico que no haya campos vacíos
    if (marca === '' || modelo === '' || year === '' || tipo === '') {
      mostrarMensaje('Todos los campos son obligatorios', 'error');
      return;
    }
  
    mostrarMensaje('Cotizando...', 'exito');
  
    // Ocultar las cotizaciones previas 
    const resultados = document.querySelector('#resultado div');
    if (resultados != null) {
      resultados.remove();
    }
  
    //Busco el precio del modelo seleccionado
    price = archivoAjax.find(elem => (elem.marca.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-') == marca.toLowerCase() && elem.modelo.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-') == modelo.toLowerCase()));
  
    // Instanciar el seguro
    const seguro = new Seguro(marca, modelo, year, tipo, price.precio);
  
    //Llamo al método cotizarSeguro de la clase Seguro
    const valorPoliza = seguro.cotizarSeguro();
  
    // Muestro resultado de la cotización
    mostrarResultado(valorPoliza, seguro);
  } // Cierre funcion cotizarSeguro
  
  //Función para mostrar un mensaje
  function mostrarMensaje(mensaje, tipo) {
    //Creo un div para mostrar el mensaje
    const div = document.createElement('div');
  
    if (tipo === 'error') {
      div.classList.add('error');
    } else {
      div.classList.add('correcto');
    }
  
    //Agrego clases y contenido al div
    div.classList.add('mensaje', 'mt-10');
    div.textContent = mensaje;
  
    // Insertar en el HTML
    const formulario = document.querySelector('#cotizar-seguro');
    formulario.insertBefore(div, document.querySelector('#resultado'));
  
    //Mantener el mensaje por 2 segundos y después borrarlo
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.remove();
    }, 2000);
  } // Cierre funcion mostrarMensaje
  


  //Función para mostrar el resultado del cálculo de la póliza
  function mostrarResultado(valorPoliza, seguro) {
  
    //Destructuring del objeto seguro
    let {marca, modelo, year, tipo, precio } = seguro;
  
    //Configuro un formateador para la poliza y otro para el precio del auto
    const options1 = { style: 'currency', currency: 'ARS', minimumFractionDigits: 0 };
    const options2 = { style: 'currency', currency: 'ARS', minimumFractionDigits: 2 };
    const formatoPrecio = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', options1);
    const formatoPoliza = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', options2);
  
    // Creo div para mostrar resultado
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('mt-10');
  
    div.innerHTML = `
      <p class="header">Resumen de Cotización para ${datosJSON.nombre}</p>
      <p class="font-italic">Marca: ${marca.toUpperCase().replace('-', ' ')} </p>
      <p class="font-italic">Modelo: ${modelo.toUpperCase().replace('-', ' ')}  </p>
      <p class="font-italic">Año: ${year} </p>
      <p class="font-italic">Suma Asegurada: ${formatoPrecio.format(precio)}  </p>
      <p class="font-italic">Tipo de Cobertura: ${tipo.toUpperCase().replace('-', ' ')}  </p>
      <p class="font-italic">Suma Asegurada: ${formatoPoliza.format(valorPoliza)}  </p>
      `;
  
    //Selecciono el div "#resultado" donde voy a insertar la información
    const resultadoPoliza = document.querySelector('#resultado');
  
    // Mostrar el spinner
    const spinner = document.querySelector('#cargando');
    spinner.style.display = 'block';
  
    setTimeout(() => {
      //Luego de 2 segundos quito el spinner y muestro los resultados
      spinner.style.display = 'none';
      resultadoPoliza.appendChild(div);
    }, 2000);
  } // Cierre funcion mostrarResultado
```

I do not how to access that data: I tried archivoAjax.success or archivoData.ajax etc but it doesn't work.

The array of the json file it's something like that:

```
[{"marca":"Toyota","modelo":"RAV4","precio":709892},
{"marca":"Mitsubishi","modelo":"Endeavor","precio":606888},
{"marca":"Honda","modelo":"Accord","precio":498929},]
```

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cotizador de Seguros</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    <!-- <script defer src="autos.js"></script> -->
    <script defer src="variables.js"></script>    
    <script defer src="cotizadordeauto.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
        <!-- <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a> -->
      <h1>Seguros Sunshine</h1>       
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>En Seguros Sunshine tenemos muchas opciones para vos</h2>
    <p id="intro">Contamos con tres diferentes productos para satisfacer tus necesidades. Seguros contra Terceros, que cubre aquellas terceras personas involucradas en cualquier accidente. A su vez contamos con una oferta un poco mas ampliada con la opcion Terceros Ampliada, que incluye granizo o robo q hayas sufrido. Por ultimo tenemos un seguro contra todo riesgo llamado Riesgo Total donde te garantiza la total cobertura de tu vehiculo. A continuacion los podes ver con mas detalle.</p>
    <div>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-info" id="productos">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Tipo de Seguro</th>
            <th scope="col">Responsabilidad civil</th>
            <th scope="col">asistencia en ruta</th>
            <th scope="col">Granizo</th>
            <th scope="col">Robo</th>
            <th scope="col">Incendio</th>
            <th scope="col">Remolque ilimitado</th>
            <th scope="col">Vehiculo de sustitucion</th>
            <th scope="col">Daños propios</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Terceros</th>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Terceros Ampliada</th>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Todo Riesgo</th>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
            <td>&#10003</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="todaInfo"></p>
  <div class="container" id="preguntas">        
      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>Ingresa tus datos para iniciar una cotizacion</h3>
      <table class="table table-striped">    
      <thead>
          <input type="text" id="nombre" class="no-outline" placeholder="Nombre">
          <input type="number" id="edad" class="no-outline" placeholder="Edad">
          <input type="email" id="email" class="no-outline" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="tel" id="telefono" class="no-outline" placeholder="Telefono">
          <div>
            <button onclick="Guardar()" id="guardado">Guardar</button>
          </div>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="info" class="shadow">          
      </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <br> 
  <div class="container shadow col-lg-6">
      <div id="contenido" class="pb-auto" style="display: block">
        <header class="p-3 bg-info text-white text-uppercase rounded">
          <h1 class="text-center">Cotiza tu auto aqui</h1>
        </header>
        <form class="mt-10 max-width mx-auto" action="#" id="cotizar-seguro">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
            <label class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mr-3 w-20" for="marca">Marca:</label>
            <select class="d-flex mt-2 p-3 rounded" id="marca">
              <option value="" disabled selected> Seleccionar </option>
            </select>
            <label class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase ml-auto mr-3 w-20" for="marca">Modelo:</label>
            <select class="d-flex mt-2 p-3 rounded" id="modelo">
              <option value="" disabled selected> Seleccionar </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center mb-5">
            <label class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mr-3 w-20" for="year">Año:</label>
            <select class="d-flex p-3 rounded" id="year">
              <option value="" disabled selected> Seleccionar </option>
            </select>
            <label class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase ml-auto mr-3" for="color">Color:</label>
            <input type="text" class="d-flex p-3 rounded" id="color" placeholder="El color es opcional">
          </div>
          <fieldset>
            <legend class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-center w-full">Tipo Seguro</legend>    
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mt-5">
              <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mr-2">Terceros</label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="terceros" checked>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold  text-uppercase mr-2">Terceros Ampliada</label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="terceros-ampliada">
                </label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label class="font-weight-bold  text-uppercase mr-2">Todo Riesgo</label>
                <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="todo-riesgo">
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
    
          <div id="cargando" style="display: none">
            <div class="spinner">
              <div class="bounce1"></div>
              <div class="bounce2"></div>
              <div class="bounce3"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="resultado"></div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center py-4">
            <button type="submit"
                class="mx-auto bg-info hover text-white font-weight-bold py-2 px-20 rounded">Cotizar Seguro
            </button>
          </div>
    
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
     <!--Cierre del form y container-->
    <br>
  
  <!-- <div class="d-flex">
    <footer class="page-footer">
      <div class="text-center">© 2020 Copyright Seguros Sunshine</div>      
    </footer>
  </div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the console output?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? Just print in console?

Comment: console.log(data) outputs the array

Comment: I want to use the data to show it in a select

Comment: I will add, the whole js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I put the ajax function inside the windows.onload and it works.

```
window.onload = () => {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'autos.JSON',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);  
            //Selecciono los select de Marca y Modelo
    const selectMarca = document.querySelector('#marca');
    const selectModel = document.querySelector('#modelo');
  
    //Selecciono el formulario
    const formulario = document.querySelector('#cotizar-seguro');
  
    //Manejador de evento "submit" del formulario
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', cotizarSeguro);
  
    //Llamo función lista select para armar un arreglo con las distintas marcas
    const marcas = listaSelect(data, "marca");
  .......
```